# jquery checkbox select sum in ONE select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello Guys I couldn't solve that problem I don't know where the problem is ?

I want to UPDATE and SUM the old value as I change my

```
<select id="ac">
 <option> 1 </option>
 <option> 2 </option>
 <option> 3 </option>           
 <option> 4 </option>
</select>
```

JS

```
 $('select').change(function(){
      var sum = 0;
    $('select :selected').each(function() {
      sum += Number($(this).val());
    });
     $("#sum").html(sum);
```

For Example I get 1 when I change it to 4 it gives me FOUR but I want it to be 1+4 = 5 how can I fix this ?

---

Here is the non-working demo  : http://jsfiddle.net/ugokay/Fmrn2/

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/maju/dPbKb/1/)

```
    var sum = 0;
$('select').change(function(){
     sum += parseInt($(this).val());
     $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

You dont need $('select :selected').each(function() also as there will be only one selected element since you are using dropdown

Comment: thank you both for answers, after working many hours I just didnt reconise that I didnt define the variable in global.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, move the var out of the function, currently it resets it every time you change the value (go read up on jQuery documentation). 
Like so:

```
var sum=0;
$('select').change(function() {

    $('select :selected').each(function() {
        sum =sum+Number($('select').val());
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum);
});
```

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ug29g/4/).